# emmeans returns similar p value for different confidence levels

Tags: r, confidence-interval, t-test, p-value, lsmeans

I am computing multiple comparisons of the mean of an unbalanced design using estimated marginal means. I would like to see the significance level of the differences between treatments for each genotype, for a confidence level of 95%, 99% and 99.9%. However, when I compute the following code:

```
   lm_height <-   lm(height~ treatment*genotype, data = mydata)
    emmeans_height = emmeans(lm_height, ~ treatment * genotype)
    
    pairs_height <-  pairs(emmeans_height, simple="each",  by="genotype")
    
    emmstable_height <- pairs_height$`simple contrasts for treatment` %>%
         summary(infer = TRUE, level = 0.999)
```

I get the same t ratio and p value for the three confidence levels, whereas the confidence intervals change with the confidence levels.

My question would be, how does emmeans() function from emmeans package calculate the t-ratio ? And does it make sense to conclude the significance level directly from these p values (e.g: pvalue<0.01 --> highly significant difference)? Most importantly, is my approach correct to calculate the emmeans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *t* ratio is t = (estimate - null) / SE, where null is the null-hypothesis value (defaults to zero, so that usually, t = estimate / SE. And the P value is a tail area beyond the value of the t ratio, as determined by whether it is a one-sided or two-sided test.

Neither the t ratio nor the P value depends on the specified confidence level. This is true of any other software that computes *t* statistics and P values.

The confidence level determines the desired level of uncertainty for the confidence interval. If your P value is, for example, 0.03, and you specify a confidence level of 1 - 0.03 = 0.97, then one endpoint of that 97% confidence interval is the null value (assuming the same adjustment method was used). A 98% CI would contain the null value, while a 96% CI would exclude it.

Comment: thanks for your response. However, the point of interpreting the significance level of the difference between the means is still unclear for me. How would I interpret the p value in that case ?

Comment: Typically, people think of a threshold of significance, say 0.05. This sets a limit on the risk they are willing to take in making an error in saying two means are different when they are actually the same. If the P value is less than that threshold, you say the difference is big enough to conclude there's a difference, at the stated significance level.

Comment: In case I have a pvalue = 0.0001, is it correct to say that there is a highly significant difference, compared to another contrast which has a pvalue =0.049 which would be then a significant difference ?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the convention that people follow.